# ¿Cómo recibir parámetros por GET en Express? JS

Tags: javascript, express

sucede que estoy tratando de implementar la API de Mycelium Gear. [Documentación aquí](https://gear.mycelium.com/docs/)
Ya configuré el WebHook en su API con esta ruta: */payment-handler-A/*

```
https://mi-dominio.io/payment-handler-A/
```

y cuando envío una solicitud a su API desde mi server (o sea, cuando creo una orden de pago), la API me devuelve una petición GET como respuesta, que se ve así en consola:

```
                       ⬇   //tener este símbolo ? pendiente
GET /payment-handler-A/?order_id=845081&amount=00000590&amount_in_btc=0.0000059&amount_paid_in_btc=0.0&status=5&address=15HvTHd7z5ZfCzXw6yofLR5msXVcQY6o5k&tid=&transaction_ids=[]&keychain_id=10&last_keychain_id=15&after_payment_redirect_to=&auto_redirect=false&callback_data=test1
```

Se supone que para capturar esa respuesta y poder trabajar con la respuesta, debo configurar la ruta así:

```
router.get("/payment-handler-A/:data", (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.params.data) //para ver los datos
});
```

Y este código solo me devuelve un status 404 en consola, y parece ser por que la respuesta viene con ese signo de pregunta `?` después del `/payment-handler-A/` y entre el `order_id=....` ya que si intento acceder manualmente con la misma ruta pero quitándole el signo `?`

```
https://mi-dominio.io/payment-handler-A/order_id=845067&amount=5938242&amount_in_btc=0.05938242&amount_paid_in_btc=0.0&status=5&address=1A1zhRPgQdEHUupKTXi1jkKJYzepacQzVb&tid=&transaction_ids=[]&keychain_id=10&last_keychain_id=20&after_payment_redirect_to=&auto_redirect=false&callback_data=test1
```

si obtengo los params y se ve así:

```
{
  data: 'order_id=845067&amount=5938242&amount_in_btc=0.05938242&amount_paid_in_btc=0.0&status=5&address=1A1zhRPgQdEHUupKTXi1jkKJYzepacQzVb&tid=&transaction_ids=[]&keychain_id=10&last_keychain_id=20&after_payment_redirect_to=&auto_redirect=false&callback_data=test1'
}
```

Que de igual manera NO está del todo bien.

He intentado cambiar la ruta en express así: `"/payment-handler-A?/:data"` y también así: `"/payment-handler-A/?/:data"` a ver si consigo que funcione, pero no.

Alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema es que estás confundiendo el objeto [`req.params`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params), con el objeto [`req.query`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query). Son dos objetos diferentes que tienen casos de uso diferente.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Lo que debes implementar en tu ruta es lo siguiente:

```js
router.get("/payment-handler-A", (req, res) => {
  const data = req.query;
  console.log(data);
  return res.status(200).json(data);
});
```

De la [documentación](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query) se tiene que:

> **`req.query`**
> Esta propiedad es un objeto que contiene un campo o propiedad por cada cadena de consulta ([*query string*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)) encontrada en la ruta. Cuando el analizador (*parser*) de consulta está deshabilitado, `req.query` es un objeto vacío `{}`, de lo contrario, es el resultado del análisis realizado según la configuración del analizador.

En cambio, [el objeto `req.params`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params), se utiliza, efectivamente como lo declaras en tu función middleware:

```js
router.get("/payment-handler-A/:data", (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.params.data) //para ver los datos
});
```

Pero no captura cadenas de consulta escritas en la ruta, sino que captura entradas que son parte de la ruta. Por ejemplo, si tengo una ruta que muestra la información de un usuario específico por `id`, la ruta podría verse:

```
/users/12345
```

Siendo `12345` el valor `id` del usuario. No necesitas usar un par `clave-valor` como se hace en una *query string*.

**Nota**

Tal como lo advierte la documentación:

> Como el formato de `req.query` se base en una entrada controlada por el usuario, todas las propiedades y valores en este objeto se deben tratar con desconfianza (no seguras) y deben ser validadas antes de confiar en ellas. Por ejemplo, `req.query.foo.toString()` podría fallar de muchas formas, como por ejemplo `foo` podría no estar definido o podría no ser una cadena, y `toString`
> podría no ser una función sino tal vez una cadena u otra entrada de usuario.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Efectivamente, funcionó!!.. Muchas gracias Mauricio